# React Hook Form 7 custom ...register values

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I need to modify my Controller Checkbox data onSubmit with custom values.

Currently, I can only submit the checked values of the checkbox:

```
form: Array(2)
0: 18
1: 17
```

What I want is to pass also all the form.questionID together with the values of form.content, not just the Checked values. Something like this:

```
form: Array(26)
'form[0].questionId="19"'
'form[1].questionId="18"'
'form[2].questionId="17"'
'form[3].questionId="16"'
'form[4].questionId="15"'
'form[5].questionId="14"'
'form[6].questionId="7"'
'form[7].questionId="8"'
'form[8].questionId="9"'
'form[9].questionId="10"'
'form[10].questionId="11"'
'form[11].questionId="12"'
'form[12].questionId="13"'
'form[0].content="No"'
'form[1].content="Yes"'
'form[2].content="Yes"'
'form[3].content="No"'
'form[4].content="No"'
'form[5].content="No"'
'form[6].content="No"'
'form[7].content="No"'
'form[8].content="No"'
'form[9].content="No"'
'form[10].content="No"'
'form[11].content="No"'
'form[12].content="No"'
```

Here's my current code:

```
{element.map((answer, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <Controller
                      name="Checkbox"
                      control={control}
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <Checkbox
                          onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.checked)}
                          checked={field.value}
                          value={answer.id}
                          id={answer.id.toString()}
                          name={answer.type}
                          {...register('form')}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                    {answer.type}
                  </div>
                ))}
```

And finally here is my onSubmit function

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    const data = {
      form: getValues('form'),
    }}
```

I tried this solution tho but nothin change

```
{element.map((answer, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <Controller
                      name="Checkbox"
                      control={control}
                      render={({ value, field }) => (
                        <Checkbox
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            const valueCopy = [...value]
                            if (e.target.checked) {
                              valueCopy.push([
                                { questionId: answer.id },
                                { content: field.value },
                              ]) // append to array
                            } else if (!e.target.checked) {
                              valueCopy.push([
                                { questionId: answer.id },
                                { content: field.value },
                              ])
                            }
                            field.onChange(valueCopy) // update form field with new array
                          }}
                          checked={field.value}
                          value={answer.id}
                          // id={answer.id.toString()}
                          name={answer.type}
                          {...register('healthForm')}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                    {answer.type}
                  </div>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do this but incomplete, anyone?

```
{...register(
   `form.[${index}].content`,)}
```

Result:

```
"form": [
    {
      "content": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "content": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": false
    },
    {
      "content": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "content": "Yes"
    }
  ]
```

just neede to add questionId in the ...register but not sure how, i tried everything lol.